# Yocto not using the configured mirrors for one custom recipe

Tags: yocto

I've a Yocto installation (Poky) mainly for a Variscite imx8 board I'm working on and I've a constraint to work full offline. Also, I need to produce the same build for other machines like qemu-arm64 & qemu-x86_64, for testing/development purposes.

All is working fine except for one specific custom recipe, where Yocto don't want to use the configured mirrors...

Here is what I've:

```
$ bitbake core-image-full-cmdline
NOTE: Your conf/bblayers.conf has been automatically updated.
Loading cache: 100% |################################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 3480 entries from dependency cache.
Parsing recipes: 100% |##############################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:01
Parsing of 2560 .bb files complete (2559 cached, 1 parsed). 3480 targets, 256 skipped, 5 masked, 0 errors.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.38.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal-4.8"
TARGET_SYS           = "x86_64-poky-linux"
MACHINE              = "qemux86-64"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "2.5.1"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "m64 core2"
TARGET_FPU           = ""
meta                 
meta-poky            = "HEAD:64a257fa22126c4a40ff7e03424a404e360ebe1e"
meta-oe              
meta-multimedia      = "HEAD:2bb21ef27c4b0c9d52d30b3b2c5a0160fd02b966"
meta-freescale       = "HEAD:407c6cf408969445031a492e2d25e0e2749582ea"
meta-freescale-3rdparty = "HEAD:88a29631809d1af0df618245430db29f2a7012b5"
meta-freescale-distro = "HEAD:f7e2216e93aff14ac32728a13637a48df436b7f4"
meta-bsp             
meta-sdk             = "HEAD:52ac01eee49b9f2f3ffec4c4037b7928d968115b"
meta-browser         = "HEAD:75640e14e325479c076b6272b646be7a239c18aa"
meta-gnome           
meta-networking      
meta-python          
meta-filesystems     = "HEAD:2bb21ef27c4b0c9d52d30b3b2c5a0160fd02b966"
meta-qt5             = "HEAD:d4e7f73d04e8448d326b6f89908701e304e37d65"
meta-variscite-imx   = "HEAD:119766d3a05012aa2ce0cb8397e5fa87b4111666"
meta-foobar          = "HEAD:ef62c5daf9145c37480ef32d35b31778f81543b8"

Initialising tasks: 100% |###########################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:01
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: virtual-gpio-4.6-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure: Fetch command export PSEUDO_DISABLED=1; export PATH="/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/sources/poky/scripts:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/virtual-gpio/4.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/virtual-gpio/4.6-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/crossscripts:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/virtual-gpio/4.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/virtual-gpio/4.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/virtual-gpio/4.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/sbin:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/virtual-gpio/4.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/sources/poky/bitbake/bin:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/hosttools"; export HOME="/home/jenkins"; git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 ls-remote https://github.com/maquefel/virtual_gpio_basic.git  failed with exit code 128, output:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/maquefel/virtual_gpio_basic.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com; Unknown error

ERROR: virtual-gpio-4.6-r0 do_fetch: Function failed: base_do_fetch
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/virtual-gpio/4.6-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.6426
ERROR: Task (/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/sources/meta-foobar/recipes-kernel/virtual-gpio/virtual-gpio_4.6.bb:do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2 tasks of which 1 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/sources/meta-foobar/recipes-kernel/virtual-gpio/virtual-gpio_4.6.bb:do_fetch
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

recipe's log:

```
DEBUG: Python function clean_recipe_sysroot finished
DEBUG: Executing python function extend_recipe_sysroot
NOTE: Direct dependencies are []
NOTE: Installed into sysroot: []
NOTE: Skipping as already exists in sysroot: []
DEBUG: Python function extend_recipe_sysroot finished
DEBUG: Executing python function do_fetch
DEBUG: Executing python function base_do_fetch
DEBUG: Fetcher accessed the network with the command git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 ls-remote https://github.com/maquefel/virtual_gpio_basic.git 
DEBUG: Running export PSEUDO_DISABLED=1; export PATH="/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/sources/poky/scripts:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/virtual-gpio/4.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/virtual-gpio/4.6-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/crossscripts:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/virtual-gpio/4.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/virtual-gpio/4.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/virtual-gpio/4.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/sbin:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/virtual-gpio/4.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/sources/poky/bitbake/bin:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/hosttools"; export HOME="/home/jenkins"; git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 ls-remote https://github.com/maquefel/virtual_gpio_basic.git 
ERROR: Fetcher failure: Fetch command export PSEUDO_DISABLED=1; export PATH="/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/sources/poky/scripts:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/virtual-gpio/4.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/virtual-gpio/4.6-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/crossscripts:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/virtual-gpio/4.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/virtual-gpio/4.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/virtual-gpio/4.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/sbin:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/virtual-gpio/4.6-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/sources/poky/bitbake/bin:/workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/build/tmp/hosttools"; export HOME="/home/jenkins"; git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 ls-remote https://github.com/maquefel/virtual_gpio_basic.git  failed with exit code 128, output:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/maquefel/virtual_gpio_basic.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com; Unknown error

DEBUG: Python function base_do_fetch finished
DEBUG: Python function do_fetch finished
ERROR: Function failed: base_do_fetch
```

While for another recipe like lttng-modules:

```
DEBUG: Executing python function clean_recipe_sysroot
DEBUG: Python function clean_recipe_sysroot finished
DEBUG: Executing python function extend_recipe_sysroot
NOTE: Direct dependencies are []
NOTE: Installed into sysroot: []
NOTE: Skipping as already exists in sysroot: []
DEBUG: Python function extend_recipe_sysroot finished
DEBUG: Executing python function do_fetch
DEBUG: Executing python function base_do_fetch
DEBUG: Trying PREMIRRORS
[...]
DEBUG: Fetching https://**user**:**password**@example.com/artifactory/mirrors/yocto/lttng-modules-2.10.6.tar.bz2 using command '/usr/bin/env wget -t 2 -T 30 --passive-ftp --no-check-certificate --user=**user** --password=**password** --auth-no-challenge -P /workspace/jenkins/workspace/a-foobar_config-qemu-x86_64-P7UCXZZXCTQTTGXXBK2PKXONLT7ZV24CPEYPZBYNT2XDAZWA3XRQ/downloads 'https://**user**:**password**@example.com/artifactory/mirrors/yocto/lttng-modules-2.10.6.tar.bz2''
```

The receipe:

```
SUMMARY = "virtual-gpio: Virtual GPIO kernel module & tools"
LICENSE = "GPLv2"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM += "file://LICENSE;md5=a23a74b3f4caf9616230789d94217acb"

SRC_URI = "\
    git://github.com/maquefel/virtual_gpio_basic.git;protocol=https;rev=master;destsuffix=virtual-gpio \
    git://git.qemu.org/git/qemu.git;protocol=https;branch=stable-3.0;rev=stable-3.0;destsuffix=qemu-stable \
    file://fix-makefile.patch \
"

inherit module

##KERNEL_FEATURES_append = "enable-gpio-irqchip.scc"
MACHINE_EXTRA_RDEPENDS += "kernel-module-virtual-gpio"

S = "${WORKDIR}/virtual-gpio"

DEPENDS = "virtual/kernel"
PROVIDES += "virtual/kernel-module-virtual-gpio"
RPROVIDES_${PN} += "virtual/kernel-module-virtual-gpio"

EXTRA_OEMAKE += "QEMU_DIR='${WORKDIR}/qemu-stable'"

do_compile_prepend() {
    export MAKE_TARGETS=module
}

COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "(qemu.*)"
```

Relevant configurations from local.conf:

```
INHERIT += "own-mirrors"
SOURCE_MIRROR_URL = "https://${YOCTO_USER}:${YOCTO_PASS}@example.com/artifactory/mirrors/yocto"
CONNECTIVITY_CHECK_URIS = ""
BB_FETCH_PREMIRRORONLY = "1"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "virtual-gpio"
```

I don't see any difference with the other recipes (at least for SRC_URI) and I've really no idea why that only recipe is failing... If I don't work offline, it builds everything without problems.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Regards,
David.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Just a nit, probably unrelated: `IMAGE_INSTALL_append` assignment should be prefixed by a space, like `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " virtual-gpio"`

Comment: Hi Adrien, thx for the welcome :-)
For your comment, I'll update it according to your advice. Thanks!